# GKE GCE-Internal Ingress does not work with Elasticsearch REST Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a `gce-internal` ingress that works as expected when using standard HTTP REST requests via curl or python's request library. However, via the [Java Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html), all requests return a `404 (backend NotFound), service rules for [ /... ] non-existent`.  I've tried the exact same routes via curl and had no issue.  The same problem exists for the ElasticsearchIO library via Apache Beam/Google Cloud Dataflow. Both use the same `org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient` which in turn uses `org.apache.http.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient`.

The ingress config is:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: es-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: elasticsearch-coordinating-only
              servicePort: 9200
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who happens to have this or a similar issue, I worked around this.

Turns out the Apache HTTP client used by the ES client adds a `Host` header as:

```
Host: host.com:80
```

Which seems to break at least the GCE Ingress class.

I fixed by setting a `RequestOption` to override the header.

```java
String host = "host.com";
RequestOptions.Builder options = RequestOptions.DEFAULT.toBuilder();
options.addHeader("Host", host);
SearchResponse response = client.search(searchRequest, options.build());
```

I have not tested this with other ports to see if the issue persists.